# Get time in and time out from two rows in a single column in MySql

Tags: mysql

What I want to achieve is to get the time-in and time-out of each eno per date so what I have in mind is to get the minimum time for the time-in and the maximum time for the time-out for each date. But I don't know how to do it since, group by the date is not working.

```
eno          dateAndTime                              Door
636          2013-01-14 11:52:34.373 7                 4
637          2013-01-14 11:52:41.780 8                 4
638          2013-01-14 12:17:12.300 7                 4
639          2013-01-14 12:17:23.207 8                 4
640          2013-01-14 12:39:55.803 7                 4
641          2013-01-14 12:55:58.003 7                 4
642          2013-01-14 12:56:47.360 8                 4
643          2013-01-14 13:43:20.453 8                 4
644          2013-01-14 16:46:19.143 7                 38
645          2013-01-14 16:47:05.397 8                 38
646          2013-01-14 17:16:30.253 7                 38
647          2013-01-14 17:17:27.193 8                 38
648          2013-01-14 17:17:47.897 7                 38
649          2013-01-14 17:23:04.640 8                 38
650          2013-01-14 17:24:40.250 7                 38
651          2013-01-14 17:25:23.360 8                 38
654          2013-01-14 21:57:56.403 7                 5
656          2013-01-14 21:59:04.280 8                 5
659          2013-01-15 04:13:38.783 7                 38
660          2013-01-15 04:14:03.283 8                 38
661          2013-01-15 02:59:26.977 7                 3
662          2013-01-15 03:00:35.840 8                 3
663          2013-01-15 03:08:01.693 7                 39
664          2013-01-15 03:08:26.023 8                 39
665          2013-01-15 03:12:49.013 7                 39
666          2013-01-15 03:13:46.000 8                 39
668          2013-01-14 23:36:23.880 8                 40
669          2013-01-14 23:40:01.337 7                 40
672          2013-01-14 23:40:39.150 8                 40
677          2013-01-15 04:35:12.970 7                 3
678          2013-01-15 02:36:52.707 7                 5
697          2013-01-15 02:53:16.810 8                 5
698          2013-01-15 02:54:07.107 7                 5
700          2013-01-15 04:58:22.440 8                 3
703          2013-01-15 05:22:49.480 7                 3
705          2013-01-15 05:44:43.357 8                 3
706          2013-01-15 05:47:26.487 7                 3
707          2013-01-15 05:47:42.597 8                 3
708          2013-01-15 03:54:52.840 8                 5
709          2013-01-15 03:55:38.920 7                 5
711          2013-01-15 05:55:44.000 8                 5
712          2013-01-15 03:56:37.687 7                 5
714          2013-01-15 03:56:43.920 8                 5
715          2013-01-15 04:10:54.820 7                 5
717          2013-01-15 04:11:08.443 8                 5
718          2013-01-15 04:12:32.947 7                 5
720          2013-01-15 04:12:38.743 8                 5
721          2013-01-15 04:15:47.843 7                 5
723          2013-01-15 04:15:54.640 8                 5
724          2013-01-15 06:20:12.350 7                 3
725          2013-01-15 06:20:38.193 8                 3
726          2013-01-15 04:20:46.910 7                 5
728          2013-01-15 04:20:49.897 8                 5
729          2013-01-15 06:15:14.463 7                 5
731          2013-01-15 10:32:13.537 7                 38
732          2013-01-15 11:10:14.990 7                 38
733          2013-01-15 11:10:25.913 8                 38
738          2013-01-15 11:24:29.533 8                 38
739          2013-01-15 11:26:28.020 7                 38
741          2013-01-15 11:36:24.213 8                 38
742          2013-01-15 11:43:19.457 7                 38
743          2013-01-15 11:44:49.100 8                 38
761          2013-01-15 13:09:51.080 7                 4
762          2013-01-15 13:10:04.207 8                 4
763          2013-01-15 13:10:21.690 7                 3
764          2013-01-15 13:12:08.617 8                 3
765          2013-01-15 13:13:25.163 7                 3
766          2013-01-15 13:14:49.400 8                 3
767          2013-01-15 13:17:20.230 7                 3
768          2013-01-15 13:17:43.467 8                 3
771          2013-01-15 14:58:25.400 7                 3
774          2013-01-15 13:18:37.350 8                 5
779          2013-01-15 20:28:59.957 7                 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySql `DATE` function to filter the time and get the date:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date-function.php

Identify the DATE() column with a new name.. so something like this:

```
SELECT *, DATE(dateAndTime) as 'justDate' FROM yourTable GROUP BY `justDate`
```

This syntax might be off a bit, I have not written any SQL for a while.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select  id, CONCAT_WS('',login_time,'   ',logout_time) from tablelogin
```